# _TypeError (type 'List<Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'CryptoModel')

Tags: flutter, class, object, model, graphql

I'm trying to convert a json object I'm getting from server to list but I get the error above. Here's my code

```
 Future getCryptoAssets() async {
    var cryptoList = await CryptoApi().getCrytoAssets();
    CryptoModel r = cryptoList;
    if (!_streamController.isClosed) {
      _streamController.add(r);
    }
    return r;
  }
```

I get the following when I print r

```
[{__typename: MyAccount, balances: [{__typename: MyBalance, ticker: BTC, name: Bitcoin, decimals: 8, amount: 0.00000000, logo: https://data.wealthica.com/api/securities/CRYPTO:BTC/logo, wallet: 1JZnxkJnNV9ymZFTqjfve1ksdM2zJq3rsN:cash:usd}]}]
```

Comment: Your response JSON is list type but you set it to CryptoModel object that is not a list.

Comment: this is because you are returning a List rather than a CryptoModel object either change your Receiver type or return CryptoModel object instead a List.

Comment: How do I make it return a list that is compatible with the Model class